# kvm:the difference between "blacklist" and "softdep"

Tags: debian, kvm, pci-passthrough, gpu-passthrough

I am newbie here and I can only find the blog or readme from github.
Is there any official documents?

Emm,someone wrote the "blacklist" on "/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf" while
someone wrote the "blacklist" on "/etc/modules-load.d/blacklist.conf".

And someone wrote the "softdep" instead of "blacklist"

For example,
someone wrote

```
echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist nvidia" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist radeon" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
echo "blacklist amdgpu" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
echo "blacklist nvidiafb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
echo "blacklist snd_hda_intel" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and someone wrote

```
echo "softdep nouveau pre: vfio-pci" >> 
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
echo "softdep nvidia pre: vfio-pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
echo "softdep nvidia* pre: vfio-pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
```

I really don't know the difference,any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: The links of these files?

Comment: @Li-GuangdaFine，I should write more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to see the `man` page: `man modprobe.conf`.

**Blacklist**: Consider a fictional module `printer_driver` that supports Brother, HP and Samsung printers.  To make life easy it could be given the internal aliases `HP`, `Brother` and `Samsung`.  Running `modprobe HP` will now load the module just as running `modprobe printer_driver` would.  However, a problem could arise if there was another module which used these same aliases, or alternatively was actually called `HP`.  Using the **blacklist** command instructs the system to ignore the problematic aliases.

**Softdep**: The example from the man page is quite good.  Consider a module `c` which will run quite happily doing its job, but it's better if the management interface is loaded.  `softdep c pre: a b post: d e` tells the system to load `a b c d e` when the command `modprobe c` is given.  However, it will not fail if the soft dependancies cannot be satisfied.  Flags can be applied to the dependencies independently of the flags on the main module.